# Efficient way to do matrix operations on Panda slice via .loc

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, slice

I'm looking for an efficient way to do matrix operations on a Panda slice via .loc

Let's say I have the following .loc slice of a dataframe with datetimeindex

```
(df.loc['07-30-19':,'2':'4'])=

              2    3    4
Date                     
2019-07-30  5.0  4.0  3.0
2019-07-31  2.0  3.0  4.0
2019-08-01  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

And there is another column in df called A (shares same dateindex) such that

```
(df.loc['07-30-19':,'A'])
Date
2019-07-30    2.0
2019-07-31    3.0
2019-08-01    4.0
```

My goal is to efficiently perform an operation where I subtract value A from each corresponding column in the first slice (cols 2-4) with respect to the shared datetime index they have.

Essentially I want to end up with

```
              2    3    4
Date                     
2019-07-30  3.0  2.0  1.0
2019-07-31  -1.0  0.0  1.0
2019-08-01  -3.0  -2.0 -1.0
```

I tried using a slice operation as follows but it messed up

```
(df.loc['07-30-19':,'2':'4'])-df.loc['07-30-19':,'A']
Out[115]: 
            2019-07-30 00:00:00  2019-07-31 00:00:00  ...   3   4
Date                                                  ...        
2019-07-30                  NaN                  NaN  ... NaN NaN
2019-07-31                  NaN                  NaN  ... NaN NaN
2019-08-01                  NaN                  NaN  ... NaN NaN
```

My work around using numpy was to essentially convert the values of A to a matching nxn matrix as the slice and then do matrix math

```
(df.loc['07-30-19':,'2':'4'])-(df.loc['07-30-19':,'A'].values.reshape(3,1)*np.ones((1,3)))
Out[118]: 
              2    3    4
Date                     
2019-07-30  3.0  2.0  1.0
2019-07-31 -1.0  0.0  1.0
2019-08-01 -3.0 -2.0 -1.0
```

**But I'm wondering is there an easier way to do this via .loc without using matrix transformation?**

Answer (score 2):

Note `axis=0`. This is not the default.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['2019-07-30', 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0],
    ['2019-07-31', 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0],
    ['2019-08-01', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
]
columns = ['Date', '2', '3', '4', 'A']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df_new = df.loc['2019-07-30':, '2':'4'].sub(df.loc['2019-07-30':, 'A'], axis=0)
print(df_new)
```

**Result:**

```
              2    3    4
Date                     
2019-07-30  3.0  2.0  1.0
2019-07-31 -1.0  0.0  1.0
2019-08-01 -3.0 -2.0 -1.0
```

Comment: If I wanted to do multiple operations (add, subtract, divide, etc) can I just chain .add(), .sub() and etc  and maintain an axis value?

Comment: @NSHAH Yes. Here is the [comprehensive list of binary operator functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#binary-operator-functions). All of the element-wise operators have `axis` as an option, and that includes all the ones you listed.